# popen on c++11 not found

Tags: c++11, visual-studio-2015, popen

I am trying to run gnuplot from a c++ program in a portable fashion. Ironically enough for WIN_32 I have no problem, but my compiler (visual studio 2015)can't identify the POSIX command popen() that I am trying to use for other OS. Is popen() nonexistent in C++11, is there an equivalent or must I change standards?

this compiles and runs in windows visual studio 2015 :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  _popen(" ", "w");
  return 0;
}
```

this does not compile :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  popen(" ", "w");
  return 0;
}
```

error 
Error   C3861   'popen': identifier not found
at the end of the day, I want a behavior like

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  #ifdef WIN_32
    _popen(" ", "w");
  #else
    popen(" ", "w");
  #endif
  return 0;
}
```

I expect this program to be recompiled in g++ when used on Linux and Mac, but I would like to use msvc14 to compile on windows

Comment: What error do you get exactly?

Comment: I don't quite get your question. Are you saying popen works in Windows but not in another OS ? If so which other OS. Why should visual studio understand the #else part when you've defined WIN32; that is what it will see and interpret. popen() is part of POSIX and nothing to do with C++11.

Comment: Can you clarify your question a bit ? is _popen() working when you're compiling on windows/visual studio ? On which platform is popen() not working ? How do you compile your program in that case ?

Comment: How about exchanging "snippet" with a [minimal, compilable, verifyable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and adding the error you are observing *with exactly that example code*? You don't need `gnuplot`, you don't need `<vector>` or `<iostream>`, just that bit to reproduce your problem with `popen()`.

Comment: I have edited my question, I don't expect the latter to run in windows but I do expect it to compile in visual studio 2015

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`popen()` is indeed not present in C++ (any version). It's defined by posix, and so available on most unix like operating systems.

There is no `popen()` function on windows, but there is the equivalent [_popen()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/96ayss4b.aspx) function that you can use

MSVC pre-defines the `_WIN32` constant, which you could use for conditional compiling, .e.g

```
#ifdef _WIN32
   _popen(" ", "w");
#else
    popen(" ", "w");
#endif
```

Comment: it works in windows, but will not compile on g++ popendemo.cpp:6:18: error: ‘_popen’ was not declared in this scope, I would like the program to be compatible in both OSX and Windows and compilable in VS2015

Comment: I expect to have to use #ifdef WIN32 and #else to address the environments seperately, but compiling is the issue

Comment: @BrettGreen I think you used the wrong macro in your #ifdef. It's `_WIN32`, not `WIN_32` nor `WIN32`

Comment: ah! that underscore really made a difference, I thought that's what I was doing this whole time. I didn't recognize that _WIN32 and WIN32 were different